# How to redirect to a specific part of a page?

Tags: redirect, joomla, sector

I have this problem: my website have a big logo which full all the screen for common resolutions, which is hard to understand that the content is actually changing when the user clicks in a menu (because the content is to low on the page). My question is, is it possible to, instead of common redirects, do a redirect which include a specific sector in a page?

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can use anchors () in your URL (like http://www.domain.tld/page1#something) to jump to a specific part of your website, but I would give you the advice to change the layout and design of your website to show your visitors the content directly. You loose enourmous amounts of visitors when your content is "below the fold". When using anchors or Javascript to jump to the "right" position, you will still loose people, since they get confused because of the browser jumping around. Maybe use one template for your frontpage and another for all other pages to achieve the different designs. :-)